# When to use AccessController.doPrivileged() in applets?

Tags: java, applet, access-control

It's true, that in (signed) applets I need to use `AccessController.doPrivileged()`  only when my applet  communicates with JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The same situation might occur if an untrusted applet gets access to this applet and calls its methods.

Also, you can never be entirely sure how an applet will be deployed or used by others (even if it is written by you and embedded in your site).

Comment: Ok, thanks. But in oracle's site wrote that if Applet accessed by JavaScript it implies to  behave applet like an unsigned applet. So it's mean that with _unsigned_ applet I can do all non-secure operations if I wrap all non-secure method invocations in `AccessController.doPrivileged()`?

Comment: *" So it's mean that with unsigned applet I can do all non-secure operations"* No.  It does not magically allow a sand-boxed applet to do things that are normally only allowed in a trusted applet.